# PHP Async Curl POST is slowing down my code in 500 ms

Tags: php, performance, curl

I am trying to scale up / speed up my application

So I am developing a landing page which save data and redirect after saving the data , In order to save the data I used another service on my server that get the post data from CURL and post it to Bigquery .

The problem is that the time for the CURL to execute is around 700 ms and when I am removing the CURL Code I am executing the code in 95-110 MS

Here is my CURL code example -

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

I am looking to lower the curl time from 700ms to 50-180ms mif it is by improving the curl code or on alternative solution

Comment: You can't make curl go faster. Get a server with more power. Check bandwidth and network latency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a solution to build async curl that response by miliseconds and no seconds

I replaced the

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
```

With

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 50);
```

That way I can limit the meximum time of a curl post to 50MS

Answer (score 0):

1) Try removing the FRESH_CONNECT, that will create a new TCP every time and you don’t want that if speed is what you are after.

When you do a CURL for the first time a TCP connection is established. When the data is sent the connection is Kept Alive so it can be reused, the default time is 60 seconds.

So it will help you with speed on every call after the first one inside 60 seconds.

2) Since you are not using the result of the curl you could put the data in a queue and send the curl with a worker.

Comment: Hey Vlad , Can you please elaborate on the second point ? the fresh connect optimized my code in 50 ms I am also Using appengine Environment  Do you think there is maybe alternative to curl ? FYI I am posting the data but I don't need to handle the result

Comment: Glad my comment helped.

Since you don't do anything with the result of the curl you can look into message brokers like RabbitMQ or any Pub/Sub solution which will allow you to post a message containing `$request_url` and `$postFields` and have a different process listening to the queue and and executing the curls. This way it will speed up things even faster since your main script won't wait for the curl anymore. I like this better than implementing timeouts which might end up with your curl not being sent.